# facebook applink fallback not working

Tags: android, facebook, applinks

I am not able to implement facebook applinks fallback which redirects it to google play store if the app does not exist on the device .. My applink works if app is installed on the device .I havent posted my applink due to privacy reasons... Please any help would be useful ... Thank u in advance

```
    <meta property="al:android:url" content="sharesample://story/1234">
    <meta property="al:android:package" content="com.facebook.samples.sharesample">
    <meta property="al:android:app_name" content="ShareSample">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add this in your meta tag

`<meta property="al:web:should_fallback" content="false">`